# Internet Explorer not loading js file

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I work in a company that has departments in several countries. At our local department we can put our own stuff on the website, but there are quite a few limitations. I've created an order form in html and jquery, everything in one file. It works completely fine when I run this file from C:\ in Internet Explorer, Opera or Firefox.

Enter the limitations imposed on our local websites: I can't enter more than 20 000 characters into an html page. I tested an early version of the form on our local website and it worked, it contained both html and jquery, but it was far below 20 000 characters. The HTML part alone is now 15 000 characters, and the jquery 75 000. Thus it makes sense to put the HTML and the javascript in separate files.

Enter yet another limitation: I cannot upload .js files to our local server. I think I can convince the guys at the main office to let me do this, but it will take some time to convince them. In the meantime I want to find some workaround to publish a functional form, so that our customers can start trying out the order form, and it will be easier to convince the main office when they can see a working demonstration.

https://gist.github.com/ is a place where anyone can enter some javascript and make an accessible javascript. I tried this out with Opera first, and it worked, but for some reason it wouldn't work in Internet Explorer. I've tried lots of different things, until I finally created a completely basic HTML page like this (insert a head to make it work in a browser):

```html
<HTML>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
  <SCRIPT src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"     type="text/javascript"></SCRIPT>


  <FORM enctype="application/x-www-for m-urlencoded" NAME="orderForm" id="orderForm"    ACTION="" METHOD="get">
  <input type="button" id="TestButton" onclick="TestFunction()" value="some value">
<SCRIPT  src="https://raw.github.com/gist/2643863/30916820b71be3f9b89ad41ef060a2dd784b620e/VerySimpleTest.js" type="text/javascript"></SCRIPT>
<!--SCRIPT src="simpleSCRIPTtest.js"></SCRIPT-->
</form>
</body>
</HTML>
```

I've alternated between accessing the .js file locally and from the Gist page, thus the commented SCRIPT line. The script is this:

```
function TestFunction() {
  alert("This works!");
}
```

In Opera it works fine both locally and from Gist. It works fine in IE when loading the script locally, but when I try this with the Gist page as script source and press the button I get the error message "The value of the property 'TestFunction' is null or undefined, not a Function object".

If it were up to me, I would tell all our cusomters to use Opera or Chrome, but I'm afraid that's not an option. Does anyone have any idea why this doesn't work in IE? And if so, any idea of how to create an external .js file that my HTML page can access that works in IE, Opera, Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: You need to load your script *before* you use one of its functions (for instance, in your button), which I don't think I see you doing.

Comment: jQuery 1.7.2 is the recent version. Since you already use 1.7.1 you should really upgrade.

Comment: Your script when downloaded from distant server needs some time to get to your navigator. It won't work if you click the button and script is not loaded yet. Place the <script> tag loading your JS in <head> and you should be fine (page display will be blocked until the script is ready).

Comment: Elliot Bonneville: I've tried to place the bottom SCRIPT line directly below the first one, but it makes no difference. It still works in Opera but not in IE.

Comment: ThiefMaster: I've changed to version 1.7.2, but this also makes no difference. Works in Opera, not in IE.

Comment: wdev: I don't have access to the head in the document that will eventually be published on our local server. It also seems strange that this should be the cause when it works fine in Opera. Still, just to check it out, I moved the SCRIPT tags inside the HEAD, but it still works fine in Opera and not in IE.

Comment: Have you tried using http instead of https to request the javascript?

Comment: Using http instead of https might help, but Gist only gives me a https. Anyway, I have found a way to solve the problem if you look at my comment below Jay Blanchard's answer.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot see the document type so if this is not HTML5 you will need to include the type="text/javascript" attribute in your script tags for the simpleSCRIPTtest.js.

Comment: If you look at the code that I've quoted, I do have type="text/javascript" in the SCRIPT tags.

Comment: Not in the tags for simpleScripttest.js.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your first post. The HTTP header needs to contain "ContentType: text/javascript" or "ContentType: application/javascript" for IE. I cannot do this with Gist, so I tried it on a local server. This server isn't accessible from outside our network, so I'll have to somehow rig a temporary server where I can control this.